# How do i find my Mobilenumber on my Samsung Galaxy 5

Tags: samsung-galaxy-5

I've been trying to give my friend my number. When I first got my *Samsung Galaxy S* I wrote it down in the memos: a mobile number that had 11 numbers in it.

I can't remember where I got that from -- and now when I try to find it, I go into *About → phone-status*, but for phone number it says "unknown".

I don't know what to do. If I click on the "unknown" thing it does nothing. I also thought numbers were meant to have 10 numbers.

So how can I find out what my number is?

Comment: Just give him a call? He should then see the incoming number.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use your phone to call a friend with Caller ID (usually any mobile phone nowadays).
2. Take note of the incoming caller's number. That's your number.